# Can we find a function with describing condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

can we find a function with the following condition?

$g^{\prime}(1)=0$

$g^{\prime}(2)=0$

$g^{\prime}(3)=0$

$g^{\prime}(4)=0$

$g(1)=69$

$g(2)=34$

$g(3)=35$

$g(4)=0$

Comment: and yes, it is possible to find such functions, just need to make sure that points $1,2,3,4$ are appropriate extrema of the function $g$.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It can be a polynomial of degree 7.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides could you plz explain more?

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, since you have $8$ conditions, a polynomial of degree $7$ could fit all the requirements.

So, let
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^7 a_i \,x^i \qquad \text{and} \qquad g'(x)=\sum_{i=i}^7 i\,a_i\, x^{i-1}$$ and write all equations. You have a system of $8$ linear equations for $8$ unknown coefficients. Write it in matrix form and solve.

If I am not mistaken, you should get
$$a_0= -1928\qquad a_1= \frac{21380}{3}\qquad a_2=
   -\frac{184865}{18}\qquad a_3= \frac{140357}{18}$$ $$a_4= -\frac{30700}{9}\qquad a_5=
   \frac{15587}{18}\qquad a_6= -\frac{2135}{18}\qquad a_7= \frac{61}{9}$$ which makes
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{18} (x-4)^2\left(122 x^5-1159 x^4+4363 x^3-7952 x^2+6933 x-2169\right)$$ Plot it to see how it works.

But other functions could also make the job.